# Remove punctuation from string expect apostrophe in Pig latin script

Tags: apache-pig, word-count

I want to perform word count on a word file and remove punctuation expect for string with apostrophe. I tried doing the below code but it giving an error as unexpected " ".

```
    word_file = LOAD '/user/username/text.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:CHARARRAY);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    stop_file = LOAD '/user/username/stop_words.txt' USING TextLoader AS(stop:CHARARRAY);
    words = FOREACH word_file GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(line)) ,'([\w\d'\s]+)', ''))) AS word;
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#replace
states

> If you want to replace special characters such as '[' in the string
>   literal, it is necessary to escape them in 'regExp' by prefixing them
>   with double backslashes (e.g. '\[').

So if you want to exclude any quoted string, I would do

```
word_file = LOAD 'input.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:CHARARRAY);
words = FOREACH word_file GENERATE 
          FLATTEN(
            TOKENIZE(
              REPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(line)),'(\\\'[\\w\\d\\s]+\\\')', ''))) AS word;
STORE words into '...';
```